# How to read excel file by row in Go language?

Tags: go, excelize

In my project, I using `qax-os/excelize` library version `v2.7.1` for read excel file in Go language. But when I run my app on machine with `32Mi` ram I got error out of memory.

This is sample of my code:

```
func main() {
    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("electricinfo.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer func() {
        // Close the spreadsheet.
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    // Get all the rows in the sheet mydistrict.
    rows, err := f.GetRows("mydistrict")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, row := range rows {
        for _, colCell := range row {
            // ...Business logic
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

How I can read excel row one by one, something like

```
func main() {
    rowNumber := 1
    for {
        // Loop through each row in the csv
        record, err := csvReader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            // ... Block of code
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the library you use doesn't support this you cannot do this. Note that xlsx is not designed to be read sequentially.

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that an xlsx file is technically a zip with a lot of XMLs in it. So the package have to extract the content of it first to read. It cannot be read without seeing the file structure in it and there are also referencies from one XML to others, so it have to be extracted.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Rows`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xuri/excelize/v2#File.Rows) to iterate through the data? (this avoids loading the whole worksheet into memory).

Comment: @Brits I think this is the way I want, I will try to use it. It's strange that they didn't write instructions for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [xlsxreader](https://github.com/kynrai/xlsx-tables) package, A low-memory high performance library for reading data from an xlsx file for streaming data instead of loading into RAM. Alternative, You can use [xlsx-tables](https://github.com/thedatashed/xlsxreader).